# What is the correct way of stopping an object in a method that was created in another?

Tags: c#

I have a form that has a button which creates a new object and calls it's `start()` method.

The program works fine, however, I now want to create a stop button. I obviously cannot call the object's `stop()` method as it is elsewhere, but, I just can't think of the correct way of changing my code.

As I write this, the best thing I can think of is to take the `MyObject myo = new MyObject("test");` and place `MyObject myo;` at the top of the class, outside methods and then try to set it from within the class.

What would you do in this situation?

Comment: What does start do? Fire of an asynchronous process, or does it block until start finishes?

Comment: AFAIK, it is async/in the background as I can call/do other code... it is a monitor and doesn't stop until stop() is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all dependent on scope.

If you want the form, at any time, to have visibility to that object, placing it as a private/protected member within the form's object is probably a good route. (make sure it's not null though.

```
class MyForm
{
   private MyObject myobject;

   private MyForm(){
     // create the object
     myobject = new MyObject;
   }

   private void Start_Click(){
     myobject.start();
   }
   private void Stop_Click(){
     myobject.stop();
   }
 }
```

If this object is constantly referenced, you could follow a [singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

If this is something you can re-create based on [an/the] argument(s) passed to the construct, you can re-create it every time it's needed.

Answer (score 3):

That is is exactly what you are supposed to do. Its called creating a member variable.

But make sure you don't call `myo.stop()` when `myo` is `null`!

Comment: The only problem is that I only know how to get this object working via it's constructor ... `MyObject myo = new MyObject("string")`... if I create it elsewhere, how would I call it's constructor, or do I have to find another way around it?

Comment: Just assign the new object to the member variable.

Comment: *epic facepalm* I blame it on coding at night! Thank you so much - works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  You have to store the object reference some place so that you can call its "stop" method later.